# Проблема с уничтожением классов

Tags: python, классы, tkinter

Есть код

```
 
from tkinter import *
import logging
from threading import Thread
class IODirector(object):
    def __init__(self, text_area):
        self.text_area = text_area
a=('''print("&&&")''')
class StdoutDirector(IODirector):
    def write(self, msg):
        self.text_area.insert(END, msg)

    def flush(self):
        pass

class App(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        Frame.__init__(self, master, relief=SUNKEN, bd=2)
        self.start()

    def start(self):
        print (msg)
        self.master.title("Test")
        self.submit = Button(self.master, text='Run', command=self.do_run, fg="red")
        self.submit.pack(side=TOP)
        self.text=Text(self.master)
        self.text.pack(fill=BOTH)
        self.text_area = Text(self.master, height=10, bg='black',fg="white")
        self.text_area.pack(side=BOTTOM,fill=X)

    def do_run(self):
        global a
        a=self.text.get(1.0, END)
        self.text_area.delete(1.0, END)
        t = Thread(target=print_stuff)
        sys.stdout = StdoutDirector(self.text_area)
        # configure the nameless "root" logger to also write           # added
        # to the redirected sys.stdout                                 # add
        logger = logging.getLogger()                                   # added
        console = logging.StreamHandler(stream=sys.stdout)             # added
        logger.addHandler(console)                                     # added
        t.start()

def print_stuff():
    logger = logging.getLogger('print_stuff') # will inherit "root" logger settings
    print("start project")     
    exec(a)

def main():
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO) # enable logging           # added
    root = Tk()
    app = App(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Поскольку я ничего не понимаю в ООП пришлось избавиться от классов:

```
 
from tkinter import *
import logging
from threading import Thread
import sys
root=Tk()
a=('''print("&&&")''')
def write():
   text_area.insert(END, msg)
def flush():
   pass
def print_stuff():
    logger = logging.getLogger('print_stuff') # will inherit "root" logger settings
    print("start project")     # changed
    exec(a)

def do_run():
        global a, t
        a=add.get(1.0, END)
        text_area.delete(1.0, END)
        t = Thread(target=print_stuff)
        sys.stdout = StdoutDirector(text_area) # configure the nameless "root" logger to also write           # added
        # to the redirected sys.stdout                                 # add
        logger = logging.getLogger()                                   # added
        console = logging.StreamHandler(stream=sys.stdout)             # added
        logger.addHandler(console)                                     # added
        t.start()


root.title("Test")
submit = Button(root, text='Run', command=do_run, fg="red")
submit.pack(side=TOP)
add=Text(root)
add.pack(fill=BOTH)
text_area = Text(root, height=10, bg='black',fg="white")
text_area.pack(side=BOTTOM,fill=X)

    



root.mainloop()
```

Но получилось мягко говоря не очень и код не заработал. Сразу скажу что проблема была в переменной **msg** .

Comment: Без ОПП и классов - это тупик, в который вы рано или чуть позже попадете. 
Уберите строку `print(msg)` и работайте. 
Например, наберите в верхнем `Текстовом виджете` - `print(2 + 3)` 
и нажмите кнопку 'Run' и наблюдайте, что происходит в нижнем `Текстовом виджете`.

Comment: и еще забыл написать: замените строку `print("start project")` на `print("start project", a)`. И еще, глобальные переменные - ЭТО ЗЛО!

Answer (score 0):

1. обратите внимание на PyQt, он значительно мощнее ткинтера
2. возмущается лишь строка print(msg)
   у меня все неплохо работает, но с двойными кавычками не работает, нужны одинарные. в начале нет смысла прлодить классы, которые создаются как основа для нового класса.

```py
from tkinter import *
import logging
from threading import Thread
a=('''print("&&&")''')
class StdoutDirector(object):
    def __init__(self, text_area):
        self.text_area = text_area

    def write(self, msg):
        self.text_area.insert(END, msg)

class App(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        Frame.__init__(self, master, relief=SUNKEN, bd=2)
        self.start()

    def start(self):
        self.master.title("Test")
        self.submit = Button(self.master, text='Run', command=self.do_run, fg="red")
        self.submit.pack(side=TOP)
        self.text=Text(self.master)
        self.text.pack(fill=BOTH)
        self.text_area = Text(self.master, height=10, bg='black',fg="white")
        self.text_area.pack(side=BOTTOM,fill=X)

    def do_run(self):
        global a
        a=self.text.get(1.0, END)
        self.text_area.delete(1.0, END)
        t = Thread(target=print_stuff)
        sys.stdout = StdoutDirector(self.text_area)
        # configure the nameless "root" logger to also write           # added
        # to the redirected sys.stdout                                 # add
        logger = logging.getLogger()                                   # added
        console = logging.StreamHandler(stream=sys.stdout)             # added
        logger.addHandler(console)                                     # added
        t.start()

def print_stuff():
    logger = logging.getLogger('print_stuff') # will inherit "root" logger settings
    print("start project")     
    exec(a)

def main():
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO) # enable logging           # added
    root = Tk()
    app = App(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Нет ошибка в самой программе. Если в текстовый виджет ввести какой- либо код и нажать на кнопку 'run', то текстовый виджет ' text_area ' должен быть выведен результат выполнения введённого кода. Но как я понял результатом является переменная msg и я не понял откуда она берётся. Вот я и прошу исправить получившейся код (ну или сделать всё изначально правильно).

Comment: У вас не спрашивали совета что лучше, а что нет. У человека есть проблема, отвечать нужно четко и по делу.

Comment: я сам выберу как я буду помогать человеку, если вам что то не нравится выключите интернет и расслабтесь

Comment: переменная создается при первом присваивании ей значения, какой код программа должна выполнять, можно пример?

Comment: Например:  print("______").

Comment: Поймите , мне нужно вставить этот код в другой в котором 700 строк. И легче этот переделать чем тот. (Код написан без ООП)

Comment: PyQt? Увольте. Инструмент создан в целях пыток. Будет сложно даже документацию найти. Держите хоть что-то. [PyQt5](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/), [PyQt4](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt4/index.html).

Comment: ну не знаю, он даже для андроида может, хоть и надо попрыгать с бубном без нормальой документации))